# Does this method cause concurrency problems?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a CoreDataUtilities class with a class method that saves a managed object context and takes care of any errors:

```
+ (void)saveContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)moc {
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (moc != nil) {
        if ([moc hasChanges] && ![moc save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"MOC save error: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        } 
    }
}
```

I call this method from NSOperation subclasses and background threads, and pass in the NSManagedObjectContext instance of the thread / NSOperation.

My concern is this:

If Thread A calls this method, and while this method is executing half-way, Thread B calls it too. With another MOC of course. Woul this interfere in any way? From my point of view it would not, because this method does only communicate with the MOC instance which is "private" or "owned" by the calling Thread anyways. But what irritates me is if even local variables in a method get "mixed up" when multiple threads execute the same piece of code at the same time. Or does every variable have their own "context" in a new thread, with it's own heap (or stack, for that matter) of memory?

Does it make a big difference if I put this saving code directly into the NSOperation subclasses and background threads? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you put a `@synchronize(...)` block around the save operation. This will ensure that a managed object context won't be saved if it's already saving.

```
+ (void)saveContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)moc {
    if (moc == nil) return;

    @synchronized(moc)
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([moc hasChanges] && ![moc save:&error])
            NSLog(@"MOC save error: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    } 
}
```

Read [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW3) on synchronization.

Answer (score 2):

The rule is that each thread must have its own moc.

Check out [Apple's Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html) for more information.

Comment: Yes, every Thread has it's own MOC. So if a thread calls [CoreDataUtilities saveContext:myMOC] then would be there a problem? The question is about that multiple threads pass THEIR OWN MOC to this one single method for saving.

Comment: If you have a moc on each thread you don't need to worry about overlapping save calls because below the moc apple handles the concurrency. Further synchronizing on moc wouldn't do any good because it would be a different object for each thread